# Problem Plotting List Data

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the following data but it's not producing a graph. It's really a graph of y = x^2 but it's not drawing the parabola.

```
ListPlot[{{0.118082595966, 0.0139434994702}
   {0.232690587709, 0.0541449096085}
   {0.323755025675, 0.10481731665}
   {0.635064375908, 0.403306761548}
   {1.03995593543, 1.08150834764}
   {1.24757861309, 1.55645239584}
   {1.24985914502, 1.5621478824}
   {1.28010876631, 1.63867845358}
   {1.39387084749, 1.94287593949}
   {1.61826799763, 2.61879131215}
   {1.69830153111, 2.88422809057}
   {1.80394572514, 3.25422017925}
   {1.91758474125, 3.67713123989}
   {2.28730359363, 5.23175772941}
   {2.55711688228, 6.53884674964}
   {2.57448915682, 6.62799441858}
   {2.71474198493, 7.36982404472}
   {2.71771672578, 7.3859842016}
   {2.79133371081, 7.79154388509}
   {2.93701701918, 8.62606897095}
   {3.00782571172, 9.04701551209}
   {3.04591389305, 9.27759144385}
   {3.19270304812, 10.1933527535}
   {3.49953826852, 12.2467680928}
   {3.96011901114, 15.6825425824}
   {4.03736035381, 16.3002786265}
   {4.0575591647, 16.463786375}
   {4.29199472297, 18.421218702}
   {4.34405373868, 18.8708028845}
   {4.46918796297, 19.9736410484}
   {4.57198457534, 20.9030429571}
   {4.84221749331, 23.4470702525}
   {4.91947589476, 24.2012430792}
   {5.04621198212, 25.4642553685}
   {5.18618600949, 26.896525325}
   {5.30244191379, 28.1158902491}
   {5.38947738846, 29.0464665207}
   {5.66413829014, 32.0824625699}
   {5.73388230655, 32.8774063054}
   {5.81283565432, 33.7890583441}
   {5.88019906487, 34.5767410425}
   {5.88076441085, 34.5833900559}
   {5.92809469819, 35.1423067508}
   {5.94314418891, 35.3209628501}
   {5.99495406973, 35.9394742981}
   {5.99758658114, 35.9710447983}
   {6.0096528019, 36.1159267994}
   {6.10348196198, 37.2524920602}
   {6.20126546358, 38.4556933498}
   {6.28446905713, 39.49455133}
   {6.30466948205, 39.7488572779}
   {6.38143491087, 40.7227115217}
   {6.50734189838, 42.3454985824}
   {6.61194694465, 43.7178423989}
   {7.02039934645, 49.2860069836}
   {7.42026450753, 55.0603253617}
   {7.4802835805, 55.9546424446}
   {7.65159058825, 58.5468385303}
   {7.7867873695, 60.6340575378}
   {7.87996240367, 62.0938074832}
   {7.91956192978, 62.7194611597}
   {7.99479343326, 63.9167220405}
   {8.01918217389, 64.307282738}
   {8.11738862592, 65.8919981042}
   {8.65173115159, 74.8524519194}
   {8.73489882962, 76.2984575636}
   {8.84784485129, 78.2843585124}
   {8.99414544143, 80.8946522217}
   {8.99792976996, 80.962740145}
   {9.03298495842, 81.5948172591}
   {9.0715072776, 82.2922442875}
   {9.09833501033, 82.7796999602}
   {9.31832039637, 86.8310950094}
   {9.36668184112, 87.7347287127}
   {9.36979559295, 87.7930694537}
   {9.63762668124, 92.8838480469}
   {9.95997937828, 99.2011892157}
  }]
```

All I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing commas between each pair of points.

`ListPlot[{{0.118082595966, 0.0139434994702}, {0.232690587709, 
   0.0541449096085} , {0.323755025675, 
   0.10481731665} , {0.635064375908, 0.403306761548} , {1.03995593543,
    1.08150834764}, {1.24757861309, 1.55645239584}, {1.24985914502, 
   1.5621478824} , {1.28010876631, 1.63867845358}, {1.39387084749, 
   1.94287593949}, {1.61826799763, 2.61879131215}, {1.69830153111, 
   2.88422809057}, {1.80394572514, 3.25422017925} , {1.91758474125, 
   3.67713123989}, {2.28730359363, 5.23175772941} , {2.55711688228, 
   6.53884674964} , {2.57448915682, 6.62799441858} , {2.71474198493, 
   7.36982404472} , {2.71771672578, 7.3859842016} , {2.79133371081, 
   7.79154388509} , {2.93701701918, 8.62606897095} , {3.00782571172, 
   9.04701551209} , {3.04591389305, 9.27759144385} , {3.19270304812, 
   10.1933527535} , {3.49953826852, 12.2467680928} , {3.96011901114, 
   15.6825425824} , {4.03736035381, 16.3002786265} , {4.0575591647, 
   16.463786375} , {4.29199472297, 18.421218702} , {4.34405373868, 
   18.8708028845}, {4.46918796297, 19.9736410484} , {4.57198457534, 
   20.9030429571} , {4.84221749331, 23.4470702525} , {4.91947589476, 
   24.2012430792} , {5.04621198212, 25.4642553685} , {5.18618600949, 
   26.896525325} , {5.30244191379, 28.1158902491} , {5.38947738846, 
   29.0464665207} , {5.66413829014, 32.0824625699} , {5.73388230655, 
   32.8774063054} , {5.81283565432, 33.7890583441} , {5.88019906487, 
   34.5767410425} , {5.88076441085, 34.5833900559} , {5.92809469819, 
   35.1423067508} , {5.94314418891, 35.3209628501} , {5.99495406973, 
   35.9394742981} , {5.99758658114, 35.9710447983} , {6.0096528019, 
   36.1159267994} , {6.10348196198, 37.2524920602} , {6.20126546358, 
   38.4556933498} , {6.28446905713, 39.49455133} , {6.30466948205, 
   39.7488572779} , {6.38143491087, 40.7227115217} , {6.50734189838, 
   42.3454985824} , {6.61194694465, 43.7178423989} , {7.02039934645, 
   49.2860069836} , {7.42026450753, 55.0603253617} , {7.4802835805, 
   55.9546424446} , {7.65159058825, 58.5468385303} , {7.7867873695, 
   60.6340575378} , {7.87996240367, 62.0938074832} , {7.91956192978, 
   62.7194611597} , {7.99479343326, 63.9167220405} , {8.01918217389, 
   64.307282738} , {8.11738862592, 65.8919981042} , {8.65173115159, 
   74.8524519194} , {8.73489882962, 76.2984575636} , {8.84784485129, 
   78.2843585124} , {8.99414544143, 80.8946522217} , {8.99792976996, 
   80.962740145} , {9.03298495842, 81.5948172591} , {9.0715072776, 
   82.2922442875} , {9.09833501033, 82.7796999602} , {9.31832039637, 
   86.8310950094} , {9.36668184112, 87.7347287127} , {9.36979559295, 
   87.7930694537} , {9.63762668124, 92.8838480469} , {9.95997937828, 
   99.2011892157}}]`

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Doh. You are correct.